# Яндекс диск python ошибка: urllib3 or chardet/charset_normalizer doesn't match a supported version!

Tags: python, яндекс-диск

Ошибка на стадии запуска, не пойму что не так, документацию посмотрел, токен получил

```
    import yadisk
y = yadisk.YaDisk(token = "y0_AgAAAABhIxeCAAlMMgAAAADezDgBFSyzc4fZRKq0aSA0_VELNggIqRQ")
```

ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Михаил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py:102: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.8) or chardet (5.1.0)/charset_normalizer (2.0.12) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({})/charset_normalizer ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Bot_telegram/ya.py", line 1, in <module>
    import yadisk
  File "C:\Users\Михаил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yadisk\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .yadisk import YaDisk
  File "C:\Users\Михаил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\yadisk\yadisk.py", line 118, in <module>
    def _filter_kwargs_for_requests(kwargs: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Вот так палить токен было не обязательно. Срочно отзовите его. Вроде где-то тут https://id.yandex.ru/profile/devices

Comment: он уже отозван. для примера вставил

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, это был глюк одной из версий `yadisk`, впоследствии [исправленный](https://github.com/ivknv/yadisk):

> **Release 1.3.2 (2023-03-20)**
> Исправлено issue #29: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable